# Plot transition from pulse to Dirac delta spike

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a Manipulate that will take a translated pulse `(u[t-t0]-u[t-t0-ϵ]?/ϵ` to smaller values of `ϵ`. My code accomplishes that, but at some point the resulting plot just disappears. Actually, I don't mind that if I could figure a way to display a Dirac delta spike at t0. I need a conditional to determine when `ϵ` is too small to plot the pulse, then I need a plot of a spike at `t0`.

My code is below:

```
Manipulate[
 u[t_] := UnitStep[t];
 Plot[{1/ϵ (u[t - t0] - u[t - t0 - ϵ])}, {t, 0, 
   Max[1.5, 1.5 ϵ]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, Max[1.5/ϵ, 1]}, Exclusions -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12}],
   {{ϵ, 0.5}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{t0, 0.5}, 0, 1.0}
 ]
```

The disappearance of the pulse seems to depend on the value of `t0`. This complicates matters even more.

Comment: How would you show a Dirac delta on a graph?

Comment: with a vertical line with base at the coordinate (t0,0) and end at some (t0,x0) for some large value of x0.

Comment: Replace `Exclusions -> None` with `Exclusions -> {t0, t0 + ϵ}, ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is just to graphically motivate the idea, then may be this would also be an option

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {
   Red, Thick
   ,
   If[
    e > 0.02
    , Line[{{0, 0}, {t0, 0}, {t0, 1/e}, {t0 + e, 1/e}, {t0 + e, 
       0}, {2, 0}}]
    , Arrow[{{t0, 0}, {t0, 20}}]
    ]
   }
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, Max[1.5, Min[1.5/e, 20]]}}
  , AspectRatio -> 2/3
  , Axes -> True
  ]
 , {{e, 0.1}, 0.01, 0.1}
 , {t0, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea to avoid the UnitStep function

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[u[t_] := UnitStep[t];
 If[ϵ >= 0.01, 
  Plot[{1/ϵ (u[t - t0] - u[t - t0 - ϵ])}, {t, 0, 
    Max[1.5, 1.5 ϵ]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, Max[1.5/ϵ, 1]}, Exclusions -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12}], 
  Plot[0, {t, 0, Max[1.5, 1.5 ϵ]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, Max[1.5/0.005, 1]}, Exclusions -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12}, 
   Epilog -> {Directive[Thick, Red], 
     Line[{{t0, 0}, {t0, Max[1.5/ϵ, 1]}}]}]], {{ϵ, 
   0.5}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 0.5}, 0, 
  1.0}]
```

[image]