# Plotting a function with Dirac delta function and its derivative

Tags: special-functions

I am trying to plot the following expression which is a function of delta and its derivative: 
\begin{equation}
y(t)=sin[\alpha t]+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}f(t)[(1-cos[\alpha t])+(\frac{t}{\alpha}-sin[\alpha t])]
\end{equation}
where 
$$f(t)=a(\delta(t-t_1)-\delta(t-t_2))-b(\dot{\delta}(t-t_1)-\dot{\delta}(t-t_2))$$
$\alpha$, $a$, $b$, $t_1$ and $t_2$ are some constants. I am not sure how should I handle the delta function and its derivative even though they may not be well defined here, any idea?

Comment: Usually `Delta'[t]==-Delta[t]/t `. For the visualization you could perhaps use a limit- definition for example `Delta[t]=Exp[-(t/eps)^2]/( Sqrt[Pi] eps), eps <<1`

Comment: First of all, please post your expressions with Mathematica code. Second, some background on what you are doing, trying to achieve would be helpful becasue the Dirac delta is not a function, it does not take a value. It acts on test functions under an integral, see [e.g. this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207552/does-the-distributional-derivative-of-the-dirac-comb-have-the-same-properties-as).

Comment: And for visualization approaches, see [Plot transition from pulse to Dirac delta spike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131838/plot-transition-from-pulse-to-dirac-delta-spike).

Comment: well, this equation is a solution of a second order differential equation, and since I am not an expert in Mathematica I would like to try to plot it there. In reality there is another similar equation for a different variable which come from a coupled second order differential equation. That one has more or less the same form but with different parameters and I am trying to see their behaviors as parametric plots.

Comment: sorry let me explain a bit more: I solved a coupled differential equations which led to $y(t)$ and $z(t)$, the later has more or less the same behavior as the former. What I am expecting is the following: if I put $f(t)=0$ I have $y(t)=\sin[\alpha t]$ and $z(t)=\cos[\alpha t]$, they give a circular trajectory plotting both together. Now, for $f(t)\ne0$ I am expecting somehow a trajectory which looks like a curve of constant curvature with two equal and opposite delta-function like edges. Here is the full form of $z(t)$:

Comment: $$z(t)=cos[\alpha t]+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}g(t)[(1-cos[\alpha t])-(\frac{t}{\alpha}-sin[\alpha t])]$$ with $g(t)$ a similar (different variables) as $f(t)$.